# .NET Core publish code to aws with OAuth (JWT token verification)

Tags: amazon-web-services, validation, .net-core, jwt, access-token

We have a .NET Core app working in Azure using Azure AD, by enabling it in `startup.cs` file with this code:

```
builder.Services
       .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
       .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AADConfig"));
```

We are new to AWS, but need to publish the API to AWS Amplify where the token will be issued by AWS Cognito using an Angular app, which seems to be working fine.

But now from the API side, I need to verify the JWT token.

I tried doing it with this code:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.SaveToken = true;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidIssuer = configs.Issuer,//"https://cognito-idp.{aws region here}.amazonaws.com/{Cognito UserPoolId here}",
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidAudience = configs.ClientId,
            ValidateAudience = true
        };
        //options.MetadataAddress = configs.KnownKeyUrl;//Knowkye url is like  "https://cognito-idp.{aws region here}.amazonaws.com/{Cognito UserPoolId here}/.well-known/openid-configuration";
    });
```

As the token will be issued by Cognito, I don't have the key, and don't want to keep it in config or code, preferring to validate issuer, signing key using well-known config or some better way

```
IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key)
```

My controllers are decorated with attribute

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

But with the above code I keep getting errors like

> Signature is not valid

or

> Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature key was not found"

I'm okay to use `CustomerFilter` attribute to validate tokens, any help appreciated or a sample repo also.

As of now, we are keeping APIgateway or APIM as the last option, as it adds cost.

Thank you so much.

Comment: As the token will be issued by cognito, I don't have the key, and don't wanna keep it in config or code, preferring to validate issuer, signing key using well-known config or some better way

IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key)

Answer (score 0):

Corrected code to verify Signature Using OpenIdConnect, well known Url.
And able to identify iss = issuer and get right config and do token verification to proceed with authentication and authorization

```
try
  {
    var claimsPrincipal = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().ValidateToken(jwt, validationParameters, out var rawValidatedToken);
    return (JwtSecurityToken)rawValidatedToken;
    // Or, you can return the ClaimsPrincipal (which has the JWT properties automatically mapped to .NET claims)
  }
    catch (SecurityTokenValidationException)
    {
      // The token failed validation!
      // TODO: Log it or display an error.
    }
```

Comment: mark your answer as correct if it resolved your problem.